# Stop parts of tkinter grid from resizing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and I tried to design a GUI of the following form: The grid layout consists of a 3x3 square, where all the 9 tiles the same size. In the corner tiles there is some text and in the middle is a number. Additionally there is one row that contains a random button. If it is clicked it changes the number in the middle of the square to a random number between 1 and 20. I managed to get the grid to look like I want to and also to make it resize when I resize the window that contains the GUI.

I have the following problem: I only want the grid to resize when the window size is changed. Unfortunately the middle tile changes size according to the size of the number (1 digit or 2). I thought that giving each row and column in the square the same weight will make sure that they stay the same size but it doesn't. I read a bit about properties like grid_propagate = False but adding that doesn't change anything for me.
I would be very grateful if somebody explained this to me!

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self):

    Frame.__init__(self, background= '#C1FFBF')
    self.grid(sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    self.Initialise()

def Initialise(self):
    top=self.winfo_toplevel()
    top.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    top.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=10)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(j, weight=10)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)

    self.B = Button(self,text='Random',command=self.random)
    self.B.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=(N,W,S,E))
    self.Panel1 = Message(self, text= 'Some text', anchor = 'center',font = ("Purisa",30))
    self.Panel1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=(N,W,S,E))
    self.Panel2 = Message(self, text= 'Some text', anchor = 'center',font = ("Purisa",30))
    self.Panel2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=(N,W,S,E))
    self.Panel3 = Message(self, text= 'Some text', anchor = 'center',font = ("Purisa",30))
    self.Panel3.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=(N,W,S,E))
    self.Panel4 = Message(self, text= 'Some text', anchor = 'center',font = ("Purisa",30))
    self.Panel4.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=(N,W,S,E))
    self.Middle = Message(self, text= '0', anchor = 'center',font = ("Purisa",30))
    self.Middle.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=(N,W,S,E))
    top.bind('<Return>', self.random())

def random(self):
    self.Middle.config(text=str(random.randint(1,20)))

app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

Side question: I tried to bind the return key to call the random function by adding the line

top.bind('', self.random())

as the last line of Initialise but pressing it doesn't do anything. What's my mistake there?

Comment: I'd suggest you using `Label` widgets instead. Set `width` to `2` and you're fine.

Comment: @TidB: Thanks that solved it! I don't quite get what the value of width means though. Is it only relevant if other widgets have widths? I.e. if width=2 will it be twice as wide as a widget with width 1?
Also did you see my question about binding the return key?

Comment: `width` refers to the number of characters; i.e. this label will always have the width of 2 chars. The problem with the binding is that you're *calling* the method instead of passing the method *itself*. As the function returns `None`, everytime you hit the return key, `None` is executed. Use `top.bind("<Return>", self.random)` instead.

Comment: @TidB: Thank you for the explanation on the width. Your suggestion for the return key binding didn't change anything for me unfortunately.

Comment: That's strange… make sure you change `def random(self):` to `def random(self, event):`. I suspect you might be missing an exception.

Comment: @TidB: adding 'event' solved it! Thank you very much. I don't quite understand that yet but I will read up on events. If you want publish an answer so I can accept it and my question is no longer unanswered.

Comment: @TidB  I am having difficulty with a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915393/how-to-stop-window-readjusting-its-size-based-on-the-text-size-inside-it), I have tried your suggestion, but I am still having problems,  what am I missing?